# Fire Thermal Images Dataset

Tags: image, dataset

I am looking for a thermal imaging dataset which contains images of fires and wildfires. Do you know some dataset I can use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for thermal image datasets. Have yet to find any of wildfires, although the [Corsican Fire Database](http://cfdb.univ-corse.fr/index.php?newlang=english&menu=1) looks promising for visible and near-IR domains.